# asp.net textbox input always restriced to 590 characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, textbox

asp.net textbox only taking 590 characters. After writing a paragraph in a textbox for about 3500 character It only taking near about 600 characters.So what could be a better solution for me to overcome this issue.

Comment: what you want the textbox to do? are you considering TextArea instead

Comment: Its a multiline textbox. textarea are created by using asp textbox multiline mode.

Comment: Then what is your exact issue

Comment: when I take that to a string its only showing 590 characters. but its nearly more than 2000  characters.

Comment: Please include the markup of the Textbox

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtAllDetailSummary" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="20" Width="900px" MaxLength="3500"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132152/discussion-between-keulraesik-and-un-lucky).

Comment: Use **MaxLength** , `<asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="3500"></asp:TextBox>`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a MultiLine textbox?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb1" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```